# Status Code: 03-57-00 Unrecognized Disk

Tags: xbox-360

I just recieved the Hardened Edition of MW3 from the Amazon Warehouse Deals:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005K8LOA2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005K8LOA2)

I put the disc in and got the unrecognized disc error. This is the only disc this happens for. I've tried multiple times and also made sure the disc was clean. There are no visible scratches to my knowledge. What could the cause and solution be?

Comment: Sounds like a dodgy disc. Can you try the disc in another Xbox to make sure?

Comment: According to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout#Microsoft) the 360 is region locked but it's up to the dev to make it region free (the opposite of the PS3), assuming the devs for MW3 didn't make it region free can you confirm the region the game is the same as the region of your 360 (ie. US game, US 360) the cover on the page you linked to looks as if it's US but make sure that's what you got since the images could have been stolen from anywhere off the internet

Comment: yes it is the correct North American region code

Comment: You may want to check the holographic ring around the centre of the disc. If there are any scratches there, sorry to say the disc is as good as a cheap coaster. I had a copy of Deadpool with this issue, cleaned it 6 times with no change at all.

Comment: I can try to see if it works in another xbox tomorrow.

Comment: A word of advice if you do attempt to return it: Don't tell them that you've tried to "clean" the disk outside of a simple wipe with a cloth designed for cleaning glass. I've had a retailer refuse to replace a faulty game for me because they believes I screwed it up while trying to clean the disk.